# python: can't open file 'C:\\usr\\local\\bin\\django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

Whenever I say "python manage.py startproject myproject" while trying to make a website with Django, I get this error. I'm using python 3.10.4. What can i do?

Comment: I think you should first verify whether the path and file actually exists. usr/local/bin looks like a Linux file path so there might be some mixing up going on here

Comment: it should be "django-admin startproject myproject"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you install your **virtual environment** and activate it, you have to install **Django** by:

```
py -m pip install Django
```

And run that command to create your project.

```
django-admin startproject myproject
```